# How massive can a terrestrial planet be and still be habitable? Will its space civilization have problems due to its escape velocity?

Tags: planets, civilization, habitability, temperature

The star is Sun-sized and my planet will be more massive than Earth.
How massive can my planet be and still be habitable. This is without its internal heat being a problem leading to its becoming a dead inhabitable world. Also, will its space civilization have problems taking off and landing on the planet because of its escape velocity?

Comment: Tech level is extremely important for this question. Also we prefer only one question per post. If you have multiple questions related to a particular please feel free to ask several separate questions each in their own post!

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding.SE!  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.  This is a great question.  From a technical standpoint, it asks how much bang the tech you selct can handle (let's say present-day tech, just how much thrust can we get out of a rocket?).  From a biological standpoint, it's how much muscle can you pack on before bone structure degrades.  Are we talking about carbon lifeforms?

Comment: On  a small planet like Earth, we seem to find it quite difficult and expensive to overcome our puny escape velocity. It's hard to define "having problems getting up and down" without wandering deep into Opinions. Perhaps there is a better or more useful metric?

Comment: See [Could an advanced species having evolved on a large planet with a deep gravity well be helped out of it from above ?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21582/could-an-advanced-species-having-evolved-on-a-large-planet-with-a-deep-gravity/38155)

Answer (score 0):

Without antigravity generators (aka handwavium tech), a super-earth can't be colonized, unless we were cyborgs. Our structure can withstand so much stress for so much time, before a series of problems set it -bones, muscles, bloodflow, they'd be strained 24/7 to work overtime. Even with aG generators, we'd need to decompress when leaving the higher gravity environments, or the bends caused by the higher atmospheric pressure would kill us.